# Child Flatlist is not accepting horizontal

Tags: react-native

I have two flat lists that I am using to make one list inside another list, both are horizontal but only one (the parent flat list) that is applying the horizontal but the child list is not applying that horizontal behavior.

```
            <FlatList
            data={carTypes}
            renderItem={({ item }) => (
              <View style={{ height: 200, width: 300 }}>
                <Text style={{color: "red", alignSelf: "center"}}> {item.title} </Text> 
                  <FlatList

                  data={item.car_model}
                  renderItem={ ( carModel ) => (
                    <View style={{width: "70%", backgroundColor: "yellow"}}>
                      <Text>
                        {carModel.item.title}
                      </Text>
                    </View>
                  )}
                  keyExtractor={(carModel) => carModel.id.toString() }
                  horizontal={true}
                  />
              </View>
            )}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
            horizontal={true}
          />
```

Comment: Could you please provide your data or paste your full example into https://snack.expo.io/ ? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you have to add a unique `listKey` prop to inner FlatList.
check example: https://snack.expo.io/SkIfGX6aS